# How to hide parent element from within a span using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hide, parent

Newbie alert - sorry

Here is my code:

```
<div class="Links">
    <a href="/testthis1.html" data-id="button1">
        <img class="icon" src="/test1.png" alt="test1">
        <span>Test 1</span>
    </a>
    <a href="/testthis2.html" data-id="button2">
        <img class="icon" src="/test2.png" alt="test2">
        <span>Test 2</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I need to remove the 2nd anchor tag with the  with "Test 2" inside of it. However, the only place to insert the code to remove it is inside the span itself. I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
})
</script>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: As there's no conditional logic behind this you could just use CSS: `.Links a:nth-child(2) { display: none; }`

Comment: You current attempt is trying to transform `window` (that in the context is equivalent to `this`)  into a jQuery object, look for his parent thent hide it

Comment: You just want to hide or there's something that should be done that causes the element to hide? If you want to hide it from beginning, then set it on CSS as first comment said

Comment: I would just do it with CSS - That said, you could run `$( "a[data-id='button2']" ).hide();`

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @Rory Mccrossan in the comments, suggesting that you use CSS for your solution, since there is no conditional logic behind your question.

With that said, what you ask for is doable through jQuery. You have quite a few options.
Going off Rory's comment, you could implement his CSS logic into jQuery as well.

Example: `$(".Links a:nth-child(2)").hide();`

Other examples would include selector logic, such as: `$( "a[data-id='button2']" ).hide();`

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3vLhat4e/).

There are various ways to achieve what you desire, both with and without the use of JavaScript/jQuery in your case.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try using selector logic. Using CSS doesn't work since sometimes the first anchor does not appear.

Comment: Let me know how it goes @WDDFB17

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - i was able to accomplish it with this CSS. It was just finding the right place to place the code.

```
a[href="/testthis2.html"] {
  display: none;
}
```